# React-native facebook reactions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, react-native, react-animated

I'm creating a module like this: 
[image: a busy cat]

However, I am having problems with managing contours around emotion.

Link: https://snack.expo.io/BJuUwZleQ

Can someone give me a hand?